Can't rebuild dokku application for Wordpress (app/.heroku/php/etc/php/php-cli.ini: Permission denied)
I had wordpress web-site on my VPS server under Dokku.
Updated dokku version with dokku-update run.
Couple other application was survived the update, but Wordpress rebuilding is failed.
root@ubuntu-2gb-fsn1-2:~# dokku ps:rebuild chuvik
-----> Cleaning up...
-----> Building chuvik from gliderlabs/herokuish:latest-20
-----> Adding BUILD_ENV to build environment...
       BUILD_ENV added successfully
-----> PHP app detected
-----> Bootstrapping...
-----> Preparing platform package installation...
-----> Installing platform packages...
       - php (8.2.18)
       - ext-mbstring (bundled with php)
       - apache (2.4.59)
       - composer (2.7.2)
       - nginx (1.24.0)
-----> Installing dependencies...
       Composer version 2.7.2 2024-03-11 17:12:18
       Installing dependencies from lock file
       Verifying lock file contents can be installed on current platform.
       Nothing to install, update or remove
       Generating optimized autoload files
-----> Preparing runtime environment...
-----> Checking for additional extensions to install...
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> web
-----> Releasing chuvik...
-----> Checking for predeploy task
       No predeploy task found, skipping
-----> Checking for release task
       No release task found, skipping
=====> Processing deployment checks
 !     No healthchecks found in app.json for web process type                          
       No web healthchecks found in app.json. Simple container checks will be performed.
       For more efficient zero downtime deployments, add healthchecks to your app.json. See https://dokku.com/docs/deployment/zero-downtime-deploys/ for examples
-----> Deploying chuvik via the docker-local scheduler...
-----> Deploying web (count=1)
       Attempting pre-flight checks (web.1)
-----> Executing 2 healthchecks                                                        
       Running healthcheck name='default' type='uptime' uptime=10                      
       Running healthcheck name='port listening check' attempts=3 port=5000 retries=2 timeout=5 type='listening' wait=5
=====> Start healthcheck output                                                        
       state=restarting                                                                
=====> End healthcheck output                                                          
 !     Failure in name='default': container has restarted 7 times                      
 !     Failure in name='port listening check': container state is not running          
f4133219f30c371adab8eb7036988a0a0b6f1a1539043eb5760d0bd3f8a5e3d8
 !     Could not start due to 1 failed checks (web.1)
=====> Start of chuvik container output (web.1)
       /app/.profile.d/100-php.sh: line 19: /app/.heroku/php/etc/php/php-cli.ini: Permission denied
       /app/.profile.d/100-php.sh: line 19: /app/.heroku/php/etc/php/php-cli.ini: Permission denied
       /app/.profile.d/100-php.sh: line 19: /app/.heroku/php/etc/php/php-cli.ini: Permission denied
       /app/.profile.d/100-php.sh: line 19: /app/.heroku/php/etc/php/php-cli.ini: Permission denied
       /app/.profile.d/100-php.sh: line 19: /app/.heroku/php/etc/php/php-cli.ini: Permission denied
       /app/.profile.d/100-php.sh: line 19: /app/.heroku/php/etc/php/php-cli.ini: Permission denied
       /app/.profile.d/100-php.sh: line 19: /app/.heroku/php/etc/php/php-cli.ini: Permission denied
       2024/05/03 17:38:01 signal: terminated
=====> End of chuvik container output (web.1)
=====> Start of  container output (.)
       /app/.profile.d/100-php.sh: line 19: /app/.heroku/php/etc/php/php-cli.ini: Permission denied
       /app/.profile.d/100-php.sh: line 19: /app/.heroku/php/etc/php/php-cli.ini: Permission denied
       /app/.profile.d/100-php.sh: line 19: /app/.heroku/php/etc/php/php-cli.ini: Permission denied
       /app/.profile.d/100-php.sh: line 19: /app/.heroku/php/etc/php/php-cli.ini: Permission denied
       /app/.profile.d/100-php.sh: line 19: /app/.heroku/php/etc/php/php-cli.ini: Permission denied
       /app/.profile.d/100-php.sh: line 19: /app/.heroku/php/etc/php/php-cli.ini: Permission denied
       /app/.profile.d/100-php.sh: line 19: /app/.heroku/php/etc/php/php-cli.ini: Permission denied
       2024/05/03 17:38:01 signal: terminated
=====> End of  container output (.)
parallel: This job failed:
/var/lib/dokku/plugins/available/scheduler-docker-local/bin/scheduler-deploy-process-container chuvik herokuish dokku/chuvik:latest latest web 1 1
 !     -----> Bootstrapping...
-----> Preparing platform package installation...
-----> Installing platform packages...
       - php (8.2.18)
       - ext-mbstring (bundled with php)
       - apache (2.4.59)
       - composer (2.7.2)
       - nginx (1.24.0)
-----> Installing dependencies...
       Composer version 2.7.2 2024-03-11 17:12:18
       Installing dependencies from lock file
       Verifying lock file contents can be installed on current platform.
       Nothing to install, update or remove
       Generating optimized autoload files
-----> Preparing runtime environment...
-----> Checking for additional extensions to install...
 !     No healthchecks found in app.json for web process type                          
 !     Failure in name='default': container has restarted 7 times                      
 !     Failure in name='port listening check': container state is not running          
 !     Could not start due to 1 failed checks (web.1)
parallel: This job failed:
/var/lib/dokku/plugins/available/scheduler-docker-local/bin/scheduler-deploy-process-container chuvik herokuish dokku/chuvik:latest latest web 1 1

root@ubuntu-2gb-fsn1-2:~# dokku apps:report chuvik
=====> chuvik app information
       App created at:                1695470264
       App deploy source:             git-push
       App deploy source metadata:    06ce92896d22c7f1697ccc29536b50ac0d8d51d6
       App dir:                       /home/dokku/chuvik
       App locked:                    false

root@ubuntu-2gb-fsn1-2:~# dokku ps:report chuvik
=====> chuvik ps information
       Deployed:                      true
       Processes:                     1
       Ps can scale:                  true
       Ps computed procfile path:     Procfile
       Ps global procfile path:       Procfile
       Ps procfile path:              
       Ps restart policy:             on-failure:10
       Restore:                       false
       Running:                       false
       Status web 1:                  missing (CID: d53a05e6246)

I have no idea what to do with it:
**/app/.profile.d/100-php.sh: line 19: /app/.heroku/php/etc/php/php-cli.ini: Permission denied
**
I would be very grateful for any tips
I tried rebuilding app and even created new dokku application and tried to push wordpress to that new dokku app, having same error.
